# Cannot enter in callback of async (synchronous) function / empty result

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js, waterline

So I'm using async, this function will output some ids and the result of the count but not "callback"

```
    getWaitingGames: function(req,res){
    var me = req.session.passport.user;
    var rez=[];
    console.log("meeeeeeeeee");
    console.log(me);
    GivenQuestion.find().where({user_id:me}).exec(function(err,data){
        var tpm_id = data[0].partie_id;
        console.log(tpm_id);
        console.log(data);
        async.each(data, function(d, callback) {
            var parties = [];
            if (d.partie_id != tpm_id){
                console.log(d.partie_id);
                parties.push(d.partie_id);
                tpm_id=d.partie_id;
                GivenQuestion.count().where({
                    partie_id: d.partie_id,
                    user_id: me
                }).exec(function(e, countRes) {
                    console.log(countRes);
                    if (countRes==2){
                        rez.push(d.partie_id);
                        callback();
                    }
                });
            }

        }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else{
                console.log("callback");
                res.ok(rez);
            }
        });
    });

},
```

Why is that? I cannot find want I'm doing wrong, seems to be the same as in the doc and I've used it before in the same way

Edit: yes I can put the callback after the if like you guys suggested but then I get an empty rez. Why?
Does async only works one level? (I mean ,here I'm inside 2 .exec())

Comment: If `countRes!=2` you are not calling `callback()`. Looks like you should move `callback()` outside the `if` statement so it's always called for each iteration of `async.each`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small problem in the code. In case of **async.each** method, in the second parameter which is a processing function, we have to call **callback()** to move to the next element. If we don't call **callback()** then if will never come out of function.

In your case, you are making call to **callback()** only if `if (countRes==2)`, but how about other scenarios? In other scenarios **async.each()** will **wait for callback()** to process next item in the data, but since we are not calling callback() so goes waiting for it.

Solution : Make call to **callback()** outside of `if (countRes==2)`. Please check below code snippet for more details:

```
GivenQuestion.count().where({
                        partie_id: d.partie_id,
                        user_id: me
                    }).exec(function(e, countRes) {
                        console.log(countRes);
                        if (countRes==2){
                            rez.push(d.partie_id);
                        }
                        callback();
                    });
```

Please revert in case you still find the issue.

Comment: Indeed, porblem if I do this is that rez is empty. Probably because I'm inside an exec which is inside another exec? Maybe async works only on the top level? Going to edit my first post with the real issue

Answer (score 1):

Need two inputs to have more insight about the issue:

1. Did you check that the condition **if (countRes==2)** results to **true**? Because if this condition evaluates to **false**, **rez** will **always be empty**.
2. If **if (countRes==2)** evaluates to **true**, then what is the value of **d.partie_id** in that case?

Please provide these inputs.

Also, **async.each** does work at multiple levels. I did an implementation where I used async inside async. So, it doesn't look like the fault of async.

Comment: Yes the conditions evaluates to true. And d.partie_id is the id of the partie (game in english). So if I also console.log(d.partie_id) I get this

10
55ba5186dba2dff017e6df63
1
55ba4e16a4ad93ac1415e732
2
55ba56131451b25619151112
4
55ba4f086ee315de1552348e
1
55ba51368c14241b1751fbd5
2
55ba56131451b25619151112
4
55ba4f086ee315de1552348e

Also I've tried to put something in rez before and after the .count and it worked. But unfortunately I need the data inside the callback of the .count